# Ler ficheiro LUA

Tags: lua

Tenho um ficheiro que quero so ler algumas linhas, não todas as linhas. Recebo por GET as linhas que quero ler, que são numeros. So consigo ler o ficheiro inteiro.

```
local inicio = GET["inicio"]
local fim = GET["fim"]
local f = io.open(ficheiro, "r" ) --ler ficheiro
for line in f:lines() do --correr lignas
    --insert table 
    table.insert(dat_array, line)
end
```

Por exemplo se o inicio for 2 e o fim 6, ler no ciclo for apenas essas linhas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Um jeito:

```
local l=0
for line in f:lines() do
    l=l+1
    if l>=inicio and l<=fim then
        table.insert(dat_array, line)
    end
    if l>=fim then break end
end
f:close()
```

Outro jeito:

```
for l=1,inicio-1 do
    f:read()
end
for l=inicio,fim do
    table.insert(dat_array, f:read())
end
f:close()
```

O primeiro jeito funciona mesmo que o arquivo tenha menos linhas do que o intervalo dado. Nesse caso, tem que adaptar o segundo jeito para interromper o processo se `f:read()` retornar `nil` (o que é uma boa ideia de qualquer modo).